# Get an actual detailed data and specs about current established Wifi link and agreed CAPABs with AP/Sation?

Tags: wi-fi, root-access, networking

I thought getting this info would be as easy as running old good `iw` with root but to my surprise it turns out even here Android manages to screw you and your expectations yet again. I've asked around in less tech-savvy communities but got no answer so you are my last resort, SE.

I'm looking to get detailed info about currently established connection. If it isnt obvious when I say `detailed info` I mean it, I don't care about basic primitive stuff like TX/RX, assumed speed, signal strength and network SSID name, I want to know current established and agreed upon IEEE capabilities between my phone interface and AP/Station. I want to know interval data, used pre-amble, etc. On my Androind 9 based phone `iw dev wlan0 link` or `iw dev wlan0 station dump` only returns basic info I can see in the UI already.

Is there some way I can get more exhaustive (but good human-readable) info about currently established wireless connection and its capabilities/specs?

(I do have root and terminal access)